# Should bind result in a Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

The following is an example from a [Haskell tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)

```
instance Monad Maybe where  
    return x = Just x  
    Nothing >>= f = Nothing  
    Just x >>= f  = f x  
    fail _ = Nothing
```

However, I am confused by the `Just x...` line. Should the result not be a monad? I would expect the line to be

```
Just x >>= f = Just (f x)
```

Comment: Hint: what is the type of `f`?

Comment: To add to @duplode’s hint, if `>>=` were implemented the way you suggest, it would be no different from `flip fmap`. In fact, this is *precisely* the difference in power between `>>=` and `fmap`.

Comment: in other words: `f` already takes care of that - it creates a value of  type `Maybe b`, i.e. `Just (y::b)` or `Nothing`. If it isn't, the code won't typecheck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes! You're right about the result being a monad, but remember the type of the `>>=` operator: `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Then, we guess that `f` has type `a -> m b`, so applying `f` to `x` returns a monad as a result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!